# Manually call didDeselectRowAtIndexPath when cell is created

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView`inside of a `UIViewController` and the `UIViewController` is the `delegate` for the `UITableView`. In my table view I am outputting a variable number of sections with a variable number of rows. Whenever any cell is selected, a checkmark needs to appear next to it (which is currently working). However, a specific section needs checkboxes next to it when the cells are created.

To account for this I have an array with headers, data, and a flag.

Here is my array which specifies the `staticFlag`

`{arrayOfHeadersAndData.append((/// arrray stuff in a tuple ///,staticFlag: 0))}`

Here is how I add the checkboxes:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}
```

And here is how I am trying to add a checkbox on the section which has a `staticFlag=0=`

```
if arrayOfHeadersAndData[indexPath.section].staticFlag == 0 {
        tableView(tableViewOfCurrentItems, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

My current error is

> "Cannot call value of non-function type `'UITableView'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is a `UITableViewDelegate` method and needs to be called on a `UITableViewDelegate` instance e.g. `self.tableView(tableViewOfCurrentItems, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)` or `tableView.delegate?.tableView(tableViewOfCurrentItems, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)`.

It seems odd that you would call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to apply this change. That sounds like the delegate is dictating details of the appearance of the table view cells. Instead you might implement the display of this checkmark entirely within a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and have it manage hiding or showing the checkmark in response to it's `selected` property and `setSelected:animated:` method. Then you could just call `cell.selected = true` when preparing preselected cells. That approach would also allow you to implement `prepareForReuse` on your cell class to clear the selection state as needed before cells are reused and avoid potentially showing these checkmarks on other rows unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

Because you calling method as a function. The second thing is that you are trying to call method from table view but as I understood that is delegate method(and your controller is delegate). So you need to call like this :

```
self.tableView(tableViewOfCurrentItems, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight setup change. If you have an array of indexes that need checkmarks, which looks to be `arrayOfHeadersAndData`, you'll want to set your checkmarks in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

You'll need to reload upon adding a new cell. And your new cell will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and get a checkmark added. So..

1. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you will check the cells against `arrayOfHeadersAndData`. If they are in the specific section, give them a checkmark
2. Reload that section only using `tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: your_section_number), withRowAnimation: .None)`